# Whats up with my hydrangea

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, optimal-conditions, hydrangea

Im located in south Jersey Soil is clay but was amended with leafcompost, micronutrients stuff and topped with 4" woodchips. Only watered it when planted and monitored the moister level before watering again...So I planted this hydrangea and it has these brown dried spots. Please let me know if I need to add/spray anything or simply sniping it of or ignore it [image][image]

Comment: Any suggestions?